# Not getting output for CurrencyConverter standard app

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

I am running the Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS version on my system and have also installed the Ubuntu SDK as instructed in:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit

Also, I have tried developing my first app as taught in:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/

But the problem is, when I run the program I get only a blank screen as my output and I see the following set of lines at the console after I have run the program:

```
Starting /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene /home/roopa/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml
Qt at-spi: error getting the accessibility dbus address:  "The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files" 
Accessibility DBus not found. Falling back to session bus.
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader 
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene exited with code 0
```

I am unable to understand what this is. Can anybody please help me regarding this?

Please find the code that i have tried to run:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
objectName: "mainView"
applicationName: "CurrencyConverter"
id: root

width: units.gu(60)
height: units.gu(80)

property real margins: units.gu(2)
property real buttonWidth: units.gu(9)

Label {
   id: title
   ItemStyle.class: "title"
   text: i18n.tr("Currency Converter")
   height: contentHeight + root.margins
   anchors {
       left: parent.left
       right: parent.right
       top: parent.top
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can anybody please help me solve this? please.... I really have no idea as how to come out of this... please help me..!  Thanks in Advance, Roopa

Comment: Does the hardware of the system play any part in this? I use Intel pentium 4 system.

Comment: Please add your code so anybody can take a closer look to it.

Comment: @tvn, Please find my edited question above in which i have added the code that i had tried to run!
Thanks in Advance,
Roopa